# power query how to extract data from text file

Tags: powerquery

I have a text file - in fact a report - that has several pages, each page having a header and a footer. The header has a string that indicates the topic covered in the body of the page. I would like to extract the body of the pages that relate to a specific topic. Headers and Footers have the same number of lines, and body has the same structure as shown in an example at the bottom of the note. How to extract the information about claims type BBB only ?
The number of rows to skip at the top of the report is unknown, as well as the number of rows to drop at the bottom of the report. Could somebody point me in the right direction ? Thank you.

```
Page 1
Claims type: AAA
Claim #              Amount $
11111                10
11112                20
.....
End of Page 1
Page 2
Claims type : AAA
...etc.
End of Page 2         
Page 3
Claims type : BBB
Claim #              Amount $
21111                100
21112                200
.....
End of Page 3
Page 4
Claims type : CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this purely through the UI. You'll want to use the `Table.PositionOf` and `List.PositionOf` methods.

Here is what I have:

```
let
    Source = Table // however you get the table
    #"Position of Claims" = Table.PositionOf(Source, [Column1 = "Claims type : BBB", Column2 = null]),
    // Remove entries above the table belonging to Claims type BBB.
    #"Remove Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source, #"Position of Claims" + 2),
    // Check which column has the "End of Page" tag
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Remove Top Rows", "Custom", each if [Column1] is text and Text.StartsWith([Column1], "End of Page") then 1 else 0),
    #"Position of End of Page" = List.PositionOf(#"Added Custom"[Custom], 1),
    // Remove rows that don't belong to this page's table
    #"Remove Bottom Rows" = Table.FirstN(#"Added Custom", #"Position of End of Page"),
    // Remove the column that told us which row had End of Page on it
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Remove Bottom Rows",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"`
```

Comment: Thank you Alejandro. I have an Expression.Error on the step Remove Bottom Rows that says: we expected a CountOrCondition value.

Comment: Sorry, include the size of the footer as the last argument of Remove Bottom Rows.

Comment: This time it runs. I am having some other issues (like it does not find Claims type...) but I suppose this is due to the text file I am reading. This helps me a lot - thank you Alejandro.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it with UI only:

```
let
    Source= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.Start([Column1],6)="Claims" then Text.End([Column1],3) else if Text.Start([Column1],6)="End of" then "Trash" else null),
    ReplErrs = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(AddCustom, {{"Custom", null}}),
    FillDown = Table.FillDown(ReplErrs,{"Custom"}),
    FilterBBB = Table.SelectRows(FillDown, each ([Custom] = "BBB")),
    Rem1st = Table.Skip(FilterBBB,1),
    Promoted = Table.PromoteHeaders(Rem1st)
in
    Promoted
```

Comment: Max, thank you. This works for me...I am a freshman and I can see you are in post-doctorate section...I still have work to do.

Comment: @DP17000 sorry for not commenting code: 1) add custom column with formula from second row after word "each"; 2) replace errors in new column with null 3) fill new column down 4) Filter what you need ("BBB"); 5) Remove first row; 5) promote headers. It all can be done with UI, except formula for the first row :)